# Unique sign in PHP Forum for my site

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to have a forum using php in the site, but i want unique sign in, is there a platform that i could integrate and share  DB.

Comment: Are you asking for a whole forum system or for a DB system?  Do you know of mysql?

Comment: I think you want a way to log into your entire site, not just the forum, from a universal login. Is this correct? This is actually a common issue that a lot of people run into. Suppose you want a wiki, a forum, and a blog all in one place. It's easy to install MediaWiki, phpBB, and WordPress, but that means your users have 3 usernames and 3 passwords. There are usually solutions for specific software. For instance, Google "phpbb wordpress bridge". Important to remember: when bridging multiple web apps, one must ALWAYS be the "master". If two applications want to be, they won't play nice.

Answer (score 0):

What about using something like Facebook Connect or OpenID. That way users only need one account. There are others out there too but these are the most popular.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

http://openid.net/developers/